# returns 403(forbidden) when using authentication scheme in .net core

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, jwt

I am doing authentication in my web application with `JWT` Security Tokens and a custom authentication scheme.

1. I'm generating tokens when a user login
2. I created an authentication handler where I validate tokens for all requests

**Authentication Handler**

```cs
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public CustomAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthenticationOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger, 
        UrlEncoder encoder, 
        ISystemClock clock)
    : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {

    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            Exception ex;
            var key = Request.Headers[Options.HeaderName].First();

            if (!IsValid(key, out ex))
            {

                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail(ex.Message));
                //filterContext.Result = new CustomUnauthorizedResult(ex.Message);
            }
            else
            {
              
                AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(),new AuthenticationProperties(),this.Scheme.Name);
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail(""));
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom Authentication Extension**

```cs
public static class CustomAuthenticationExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCustomAuthentication(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, string authenticationScheme, string displayName, Action<CustomAuthenticationOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        return builder.AddScheme<CustomAuthenticationOptions, CustomAuthenticationHandler>(authenticationScheme, displayName, configureOptions);
    }
}
```

**Integrate Custom Authentication into Startup**

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Person>());
        services.AddTransient<IRepositoryWrapper, RepositoryWrapper>();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddAuthentication(options=> {
            options.DefaultScheme = "CustomScheme";
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "CustomScheme";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "CustomScheme";
        }).AddCustomAuthentication("CustomScheme", "CustomScheme", o => { });

    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Information);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();

    }
}
```

**Use Authentication scheme within Controller**

```cs
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="CustomScheme")]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/controller")]
    public class UserController : BaseController
    {
        
        public UserController(IRepositoryWrapper repository) : base(repository)
        {
        }
        
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Users> Get()
        {
            return _repository.Users.FindAll();
        }
    }
```

When I call the API from Postman with a valid token it returns a `403` error.

Please help to solve this...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I used `CustomAuthenticationMiddle` class instead of `AuthenticationHandler` class

```cs
public class CustomAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public CustomAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
            try
            {
                Exception ex;
                var key = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].First();

                if (!IsValid(key))
                {
                       //logic for authentication
                }
                else
                {

                    await _next.Invoke(context);
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
                return;
            }
        }

    private bool IsValid(string key)
    {
        //Code for checking the key is valid or not
    }
}
```

Replace All above Code for Integrate Custom Authentication Handler with the next line under `Startup` class

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<CustomAuthenticationMiddleware>();
```

Comment: Seems more like a workaround. In a Middleware you can surely do whatever you want, but the AuthenticationHandler ensures you are following the expected "pipeline". Here the question is why, despite you return Success in the handler, it becomes un-success. I was looking for that answer here

Comment: This solution isn't a workaround, it is another way to apply your Custom Authentication, here is the article including This way: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/12/20/net-6-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api#project-structure

Answer (score 20):

For anyone else running into this problem:

The original issue appears to be that a ClaimsIdentity was not passed to the ClaimsPrincipal when returning the AuthenticationResult in AuthenticationHandler. Note also that the authentication type must be passed to the ClaimsIdentity, or IsAuthenticated will be false. Doing something like this within the AuthenticationHandler should fix the issue:

```
else
{
    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");
    claimsPrincipal.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsPrincipal, this.Scheme.Name);

    return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely the answer.

Comment: In my case, I was missing parameter `authenticationType` of ClaimsIdentity. Apparently, you can write everything, but it does not work if not specified.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to Explain the two answers to this Question as Both are correct.

**About [First Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65941576/1908296) By [@mskowron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15100468/mskowron):**

Is the solution for 403 Error in case using the same Custom Authentication Handler Implementation under the Question as questioner missing for define Authentication Schema type under `ClaimIdentity` instance initialization, Here is a full implementation of `CustomAuthenticationHandler` class with fix bug

```cs
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public CustomAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthenticationOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger, 
        UrlEncoder encoder, 
        ISystemClock clock)
    : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {

    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var key = Request.Headers[Options.HeaderName].First();
            
            Exception vaildationException;
            if (!IsValid(key, out vaildationException))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail(vaildationException.Message));
            }
            else
            {
                // ----->> Here Changes
                var claims = new[] {}; // define claims what's you need
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "JWT");
                var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsPrincipal, this.Scheme.Name);

                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail(""));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is [An article](https://dotnetthoughts.net/implementing-basic-authentication-in-minimal-webapi/) for the same solution, But for `Basic` Authentication

**About [Second Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536846/1908296) By [Who Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10289046/tejas):**

Is another Way to Implement A Custom Authentication Different from an already exists in Question By depends on implementing a custom Authentication Middleware instead of depending on the default Dotnet Core Authentication Middleware.

Here is [An Article](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/12/20/net-6-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api#project-structure) for this solution approach, But for `Basic` Authentication.